# Blocking mobile devices other than iPhone, iPod and iPAD and desktop

Tags: user-agent

Hi we have a requirement where in we have to show mobile site if it is iPhone, iPOD or iPAD. Any devices other than these should get Device not supported message.
If it is desktop then redirect to desktop site.

**Question**: How can I identify that the device is not iPOD (iPAD, iPhone) and also this is not a desktop as it sounds difficult to get exhaustive list of universal mobile devices from user agent.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: we can identify whether it is iPhone, iPad or iPod however it is not feasible to identify that it is a mobile browser/devices (like Android, Windows and so on) or desktop.

Comment: Is there a reason that non i devices are excluded? Surely as long as the resolution is the same then it does not matter?

Comment: Yes, there are some components we are using and that does not work on non i devices. Further, this is what business requirement - so I don't think I can alter that. Additionally, we operate in very strict environment where things will not go without extensive testing and we do not have enough bandwidth to test for other devices..and so on.

Comment: CoolBlue2000, I didn't get about resolution? please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Can we say that if the userAgent contains "mobile" it is a mobile device? if so, what about Tablet?

Comment: I say that as a well designed website should work in all major browsers and by only supporting I devices you are ignoring the majority of potential users.

Comment: You can look for the mobile keyword, however it is entirely up to the browser what it claims as its user agent. In fact you can get plugins for firefox etc which spoof the useragent to make it look like a different browser. There really is no 100% accurate way to determine which browser is accessing your site which is why it is always better to design the site properly in the first place so that it works on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply look at the aspect ratio which is pretty unique to I devices with regard to mobile. Also surely if you can tell if it is an I device then all other devices are not supported? Therefore you do not need to identify anything other than I devices. Then direct all other devices to the desktop site. (As long as the desktop site is designed properly it should work well enough on Android and Windows Phone devices). In fact I generally always point my android tablet and phone at the dektop version of the sites anyway as they normally have better functionality.